# Is there a way to create a dynamic option form using Node JS?

Tags: html, node.js, express, server, client

I am using Express and Node JS to create a form that is stored in a google sheets using the Google Sheets API. I managed to correctly make a form that stores into the specific sheet, though there is a sub sheet I am reading, which I am able to get the value, as the correct value is shown in the console.

My issue is that I need to make an option tag based upon what I read in, for example:
**Names: John Doe, Jane Doe, ... , SomeName Doe**

I cannot find a way to create a dynamic option tag for this. I have tried using JSDOM, though I cannot pass through the value (In the example above, name) into the option tag. Is there any way to do it?

**Form EJS:**

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Bus Garage Form</h3>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%;" class="container">
   <div>
      <form action="/save" method="post">
          <label for="name">Name List: </label>
          <select id="name" name="name">
             <!--Dynamic List One-->
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <label for="list2">List 2: </label>
          <select id="list2" name="list_2">
             <!--Dynamic List Two-->
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <label for="val1">Value Float: </label>
          <input id="val1" name="val_1" type="number" step="0.1">
          <br><br>
          <label for="val2">Value Int: </label>
          <input id="val2" name="val_2" type="number">
          <br><br>
          <label for="val3">Value Date: </label>
          <input id="val3" name="val_3" type="date">
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Node JS (Portion that I need):**

```
    googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetID,
        range: rng,
        }, (err, result) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('form');
            
            var i;
            var resultArray = result.data.values;
            const numRows = resultArray ? resultArray.length : 0;
            const {window} = new JSDOM(``, {runScripts: 'outside-only'});
            
            console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved, ${resultArray[0][0]} is the first value`);
            for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
                window.eval(`
                    var sel = document.getElementById('name');
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = ${resultArray[i][0]};
                    opt.text = ${resultArray[i][0]};
                    sel.appendChild(opt);
                `);
            }
            
        }
    });
```

The error I am getting is an **Unhandled Promise Rejection** (within the window.eval(``)). I am not sure how to pass through the value with JSDOM, though I am open to other ideas as well.
**JSDOM Github:** https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: Looks like name should be quoted here: `var sel = document.getElementById(name);` like this: `var sel = document.getElementById('name');`

Comment: Yup, I just realized this as I posted it! Though sadly that isn't my issue. It's managing to get the ${resultArray[i][0]} to get put into the value and text option tag. I am unsure how to pass it through, at least with JSDOM.